# Functional equation for Hecke $L$-series

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series

In Silverman's Advanced Topics in the Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves, Theorem II.10.3, we have

> Let $L(s,\psi)$ be the Hecke $L$-series attached to the Größencharakter $\psi$. Then $L(s,\psi)$ has an analytic continuation to the entire complex plane and satisfies a functional equation relating its values at $s$ and $N-s$ for some real number $N = N(\psi)$.

After reading Tate's thesis I'm somewhat uneasy about this claim. It seems that the functional equation should relate $L(s,\psi)$ to $L(1-s,\overline{\psi})$; and in particular, $N$ is always $1$.

The later results (II.10.5.1) seem to require a functional equation relating $L(s,\psi)$ to either $L(2-s,\overline{\psi})$ or $L(2-s,\psi)$. I don't know what this could be. Can anybody help?

Comment: Dear AsDf, It seems that your question has been more-or-less answered, but it seems worth mentioning that you have to be careful when thinking about the symmetry $s \to N - s$ for an $L$-function, since change of variables $s \mapsto s - a$ changes this symmetry to $s \mapsto N - 2a - s.$  Thus it is always possible to translate the variable so that $N - 2a  = 1$ and thus have a functional equation involving $s \mapsto 1 - s$.  This is what happens in Tate's thesis, provided that the character is *unitary*.  (For this and related reasons, this is sometimes called the unitary normalization.)

Comment: If $\psi$ is the Grossencharater arising from an elliptic curve, though, it is not unitary (at least, it doesn't naively appear as such, and algebraic number theorists don't usually renormalize it to be unitary), and hence one gets a functional equation of the form $s \mapsto 2 - s$.  (To get to the unitary normalization, then, one would have to make the substitution $s \mapsto s - 1/2$.  This $1/2$ is the same $1/2$ that appears as the exponent in the Riemann hypothesis.)  Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both statements are correct. What is going on here is that the Groessencharacter of an elliptic curve with CM satisfies some relation like $\overline{\psi(x)} = \psi (x^\sigma) \varepsilon(x)$, where $\varepsilon$ is the norm character and $x \mapsto x^\sigma$ is the action of complex conjugation on the ideles of $K$. Since multiplying a Groessencharacter by a power of $\varepsilon$ just shifts its Hecke L-series, this relates the functional equation a la Tate and a la Silverman.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm still a bit confused that both can be true - since $L(E,s)$ is related to $L(E,2-s)$ by II.10.5.1; but also with $L(E,s) = L(s,\psi)L(s,\overline{\psi})$ the functional equation from Tate's thesis should relate $L(E,s)$ to $L(E,1-s)$. Do you mean that both of these are essentially the same?

Comment: I don't know where you're getting $L(E, s) = L(s, \psi) L(s, \bar\psi)$ from -- the statement is that $L(E, s) = L(s, \psi)$.

Comment: $L(E,s) = L(s,\psi)L(s,\overline{\psi})$ is the result of Deuring - it's theorem II.10.5(a) in Silverman; at least in the case that $E$ has complex multiplication by a subfield of $L$. My trouble is to reconcile this with knowing that $L(s,\psi)$'s functional equation has its critical strip at $\mathfrak{Re}(s) = 1/2$.

Comment: Ah, I was assuming that the base field was $\mathbb{Q}$. Anyway the comments above still apply. It is certainly *not* true that $L(E, s) = L(E, 1-s)$!